# how does the HTTP protocol behind client/server communication works?

Tags: http, protocols

HTTP is client - server communication where client always initiates the connection and server responds.

In the client server communication with HTTP 1.1 the following steps takes place:
1. Client sends the request to the server.
2. Server sends the response to the client with the response message and the status code.

My question is how is the data transfer handled in the protocol? I know HTTP is stateless and also it is either everything or nothing mechanism but how do you prove this? How is the handshake between server and client?

For example: When the server sends the response back to the client, what happens if 50% of the data is sent and then there is connection loss...then what will happen in this scenario? Will the client wait for remaining 50% of the message or it will start new transfer where server tries to send 100% of the message again? (In synchronous communication)

Comment: This is why such requests have a timeout. if no response is given within the timeout, connection loss or error is assumed.

Comment: Yes I get that when there is timeout but how can we confirm that 100% message is received to the client from the server? does the client sends back anything to the server in the protocol that can validate this?

Comment: yes! http status codes! lookie here : https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml

Comment: (please note, you are asking about HTTP, i think you're after what happens on the TCP layer)

Comment: Yes, thanks for correcting me. sorry to bother u with my silly question. When there is 200, OK, does that mean server is sending 200, OK to client that message is sent to the client, and as well as Client also sends 200, OK to the server? Is that 2-way?

Comment: No, if http sends a request to the server, and the server cannot read it, it will either ask the client to do the request again, or notify the client that transport has failed with a non-success status code. the client does not send a status code along with the request

Comment: Yes, your right about the request flow....but my question was more what happens in the response flow (Server sending the response message to client, how can server understand that 100% data sent and how can client ensure that 100% data received). If my understanding is correct, by default in HTTP, server will just SEND and it doesn't care if client received or not. its upto the client to look for content length and do other processing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148233/discussion-between-timothy-groote-and-user3384231).

Answer (score 0):

HTTP relies on a TCP connection, so in your example if 50% of the data is correctly sent but others packets (yes, you should think in terms of packets) are lost, the data will be sent again following the rules defined in TCP protocol

Comment: So lets say retry are not enabled then we will get timeout that means data lost...what happens if 100% data sent to client...then internally in the protocol how does the client informs the server that yes entire data received?

Comment: It doesnt, explicitly. If there is data being sent back to the client, the client can check the content-length header to confirm that it has received all of the content the server expected it to receive. If the client wants more / different information, it will make a new request to the server

Comment: Ok, I will just conclude my understanding please correct me if im saying anything wrong. When the server sends the response to the client there is no way it can be confirmed that server has sent 100% data to the client and client can again acknowledge by saying that yes, I got all 100% data? and In http, server cannot validate that client actually received the response, it can just "Send". am i right?

Comment: @user3384231 no, a server *can* validate that, that's what the TCP layer is for.

Comment: @TimothyGroote can you explain further please?